# How do I specify domain to disable x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN in Java WebAppSecurityConfig

Tags: java, iframe, x-frame-options

I know you can disable X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN header option by adding `http.headers().frameOptions().disable();` in WebAppSecurityConfig configure but I want it disabled in specific domain or url. How would I do it?